Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 when setCategory RTCAudioSession to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
I'm writing a react native code to watch livestream by using WebRTC plugin. The default audio session category is AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, that make some problems: poor sound quality than media speaker, inability to set volume to 0, and moreover, it requires microphone access.
When I try to setCategory of RTCAudioSession to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. I encountered this error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"
This is my native code, I call it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate.m
  @try {
    NSError *error = nil;
    RTCAudioSession* session = [RTCAudioSession sharedInstance];
    RTCAudioSessionConfiguration* config = [RTCAudioSessionConfiguration webRTCConfiguration];

    [session lockForConfiguration];
    
    config.category = AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback;
    config.categoryOptions = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker;
    
    [session setCategory:config.category withOptions:config.categoryOptions error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"LMT Error setCategory: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"LMT Audio session setCategory successfully.");
    }
    [session setMode:config.mode error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"LMT Error setMode: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"LMT Audio session setMode successfully.");
    }

    [session unlockForConfiguration];
  } @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"LMT Error: %@", exception);
  }
}

The error:

Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"

I want to change it to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback for play stream with media speaker
Platform Information

React Native Version:  0.71.3 0.63.4
WebRTC Module Version: 111.0.6
Platform OS + Version: IOS


Are you assigning any URL to player ? Would you please update the code. May be they contains spaces.
